# How to access value in Object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this Array Object that looks like this:

```
let arr = [
 {Name: "sub", Value: "ababbnnn"}
 ]
```

I'm trying to access the value of the Name custom:network meaning I want to output this: **abcdef1233bfgh**. So far I have this loop but I wonder if there may be a cleaner way. Thanks a lot in advance. Here's my code:

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```
const value = arr.find(item => item.Name === "custom:network").Value
```

To cover the case where no item is returned by `find`, you can use the following approach:

```
const value = (arr.find(item => item.Name === "custom:network") || {}).Value
```

Comment: Notice that this throws an exception if no object is found.

Comment: @Bergi what would be your approach?

Comment: shouldn't Value's first character be lowercase?

Comment: `(arr.find(item => item.Name === "custom:network")||{}).Value` would be my approach here... Since we know it's an array of Objects, if one is found, it's always going to return that, if none are found, it just returns `undefined`